# How can I paint on specific objects using Java Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I am working on a program for a project that will draw two graphs after performing some calculations. I already have an idea on how to draw the graphs themselves, but the problem I am facing is the fact that I don't know a good way to draw on a swing application. I understand how the graphics class works on its own canvas, but I'm unsure how to add drawings to an existing swing app.

[image: Application Window]

This is the application I'm using. The graphs should go in the spots above V Diagram and M diagram. The components are just JPanels right now, because I'm unsure what to use. If anyone knows a good way to draw lines on these sections, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1080, 720);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{30, 100, 0, 100, 30, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{30, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 30, 0, 30, 0, 30, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);
    
    editorPane_1 = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_editorPane_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_editorPane_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_editorPane_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_editorPane_1.gridx = 2;
    gbc_editorPane_1.gridy = 1;
    editorPane_1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    frame.getContentPane().add(editorPane_1, gbc_editorPane_1);
    
    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("V Diagram");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblNewLabel_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridx = 2;
    gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridy = 2;
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1, gbc_lblNewLabel_1);
    
    editorPane_2 = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_editorPane = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_editorPane.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_editorPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_editorPane.gridx = 2;
    gbc_editorPane.gridy = 4;
    editorPane_2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    frame.getContentPane().add(editorPane_2, gbc_editorPane);
    
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("M Diagram");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblNewLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 2;
    gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 5;
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel, gbc_lblNewLabel);
    
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_scrollPane.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc_scrollPane.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 1;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 7;
    scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);
    
    jta = new JTextArea();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(jta);
    jta.setLineWrap(true);
    jta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jta.setEditable(false);
    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)jta.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
    
    jta2 = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textArea.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_textArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_textArea.gridx = 2;
    gbc_textArea.gridy = 9;
    jta2.addActionListener(this);
    jta2.setHorizontalAlignment((int) JTextField.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    jta2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    frame.getContentPane().add(jta2, gbc_textArea);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is the code I use to initialize my window. I just used eclipse windowbuilder to create it because I'm not experienced with layouts. The elements that aren't declared in the method are declared at the beginning of the program since I need to use them throughout.

Comment: Depending on what you to do check out [RootPanes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) (in particular `glassPane`).  Also check out [JLayer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JLayer.html).  Also, search this site with the following tags `[java] [glasspane] [jlayer]`

Comment: Why do not create a `GraphPane` which extends from `JPanel` and then you can use `paintComponent` to simply paint what you want (adding this to your UI)?

Comment: *I am facing is the fact that I don't know a good way to draw on a swing application.* - read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for examples to get you started.